# Нет переводов в причинах "Оставить вопрос закрытым"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, причины-закрытия

Куда-то опять все переводы подевались. В очереди на переоткрытие, если проголосовать как "Оставить закрытым", то появляется всплывающее окно:

> [image: Окно причины почему вопрос нужно оставить закрытым]

Comment: А разве эти строки вообще когда-то переводились?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16800
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16801
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16799
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16803
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16797
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16798
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16839
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16796
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16795

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev. 2021.9.1.40119